# right submit in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, submit

Hi I've got a problem with submitting my own simple form in Wordpress it always redirects me to the page witch not exists. I use almost all thing for action field in form like `(get_permalink,$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])` and even did it manually.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST["email"]) && $_POST["email"]) {
    $content = "user email: {$_POST["email"]}; phone : {$_POST['phone']} ";
    $subject = "Test email ";
    $to = "some@gmail.com";

    $status = wp_mail($to,$subject,$content);
    }
?>


<div class="center form-wrapper">
<form action="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" method="post">    
<h2 class="center white form-logo">
    Subscribe
</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter name" name="name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter phone number" name="phone">
    <input type="hidden">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" >
</form>
```

Comment: `<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>` what it is showing?

Comment: It shows right way to the page but when i send a form in redirect me to the 404 page and i have no idea why is it so.It's showing http://mysite/page_where_form_is/.

Comment: i think it must be either extension missing in action like `.php` or `.html` or full url `http://.....` needed

Comment: I just check and the address is right if I send empty form everything works pretty well, and what's more odd that when I send form with empty name form it works, but if I put anything in the name input it  immediately sends me to the 404.

Comment: If you have problems with the name input, does renaming that field to something like my_form_name help?

Comment: Ye thanks it solved the problem, but it's still unclear why it causes the error.But thanks for the help anyway.